# static vs const member functions

Tags: c++

I find it difficult to decide when to use private static member functions and when to use private const member functions.

Let's say we have a method DoSomething() that needs to check if one or more members is something:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void DoSomething()
    {
         // if(IsASomething()) ...
         // or
         // if(IsSomething(a_)) ...
private:

    int* a_;
    int* b_;

    static bool IsSomething(int* n) {return n != null;}

    bool IsASomething() const { return a_ != null;}
    bool IsBSomething() const{ return b_ != null;}
};
```

When a helper function will only be used in one way (say only to check if a_ is something), i tend to go with a const member function. If it will be used with several parameters, I tend to stick with the static version. Are there other factors that I haven't thought of would persuade me to choose differently?

**Edit: I think I explained myself poorly, so I added definitions to the example.**

Comment: Why even make them member functions at all? If they're `private` there's a good chance you can hoist them out of the class and perform the check in a function inside an unnamed namespace in the cpp file.

Comment: Interesting reading: [how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197?pgno=1)

Comment: You certainly can't get confused between them, as they are not related. You must read some standard text on that.

Comment: @JonnyHenly @harpribot: OP wants to know which one choose between (example) `c.begin()` vs `begin(c)` (but for private stuff).

Comment: @JonnyHenly: The question was poorly written, but the question was which *style* is better between the both methods. (And I tend for a 3rd one :) but near of the static one)

Comment: @Jarod42 ahh I see. Thanks for liniking to the article written by Scott Meyers in your comment above, it was an interesting read.

Answer (score 4):

1. `static` functions cannot use any non-static member functions or variables.
2. `static` functions cannot be overridden polymorphically.
3. You can take an *address* of a `static` function.
4. You don't need an instance of your class to call a `static` function.
5. A member function marked `const`, *can* access class members, call other `const` functions, *and* be overridden polymorphically if marked `virtual`.

Comment: @Jaciq: you may call `Foo::IsSomething(nullptr);`, so without instance.

Comment: @Jarod42 Wouldn't that require the function to be public?

Comment: @Jaciq :May be call from a friend, from a lambda created inside `Foo` (instance or not). (BTW, it was not clear from your first remark that it was related to visibility).

Comment: @Jarod42 I hadn't considered lambda, and I suppose a case with friend could happen, although I think it would be bad design personally.
And yes, could have worded the comment more clearly. Seemed to be that the answer did not distinguish between public and private static methods.

Answer (score 4):

`const` after the function means "this function does not modify any class members [except those marked `mutable`].

`static` means "this function does not have a hidden `this` pointer passed to the function", so is really just like any free function that isn't part of the class, except it's kind of "namespaced" inside the class.

They are completely and utterly different "animals".

Edit: It really comes down to what makes most sense for the class/system design. It is typically right to use `static` functions for things that are not actually part of the class as such. I very rarely use `static` functions, since they make little sense except in some very special circumstances - the question to ask here is, "if I make this static, why is it part of this class at all?", and if the answer is "because it belongs on the class as it ", then it should be a `static` function. On the other hand, if the answer isn't a solid reason, then it probably doesn't belong in the class and should end up as static free functions (perhaps in an anononymous namespace) in the source file, rather than in a class.

In my compiler project (a total of around 13,000 lines of C++ code), I have:

- One `static` member function (to translate a string into a keyword token in the token class - because it's called during the construction of the token itself, and thus isn't suitable as a member-function).
- Around 50 `static` functions inside .cpp files that are not member functions. These do things like:

  - `IsConstant()` for some expression

    - No, I don't want that as a member function of the expression itself, as that is a generic class that can express lots of things, which would mean that I'd have to have a few dozen `return false` implementations of a virtual function, for a relatively rare case]
  - Error functions (printing an error message)
  - One could make them static members, but users of the class don't need to use these functions, which means that exposing them to the outside is pretty pointless.

Comment: OP wants to know which one choose between (example) `c.begin()` vs `begin(c)` (but for private stuff).

Comment: I think I may have phrased the question poorly. I understand the difference between const and static member functions, I was just pointing out that they can be used in a very similar manner and that I find it difficult to choose.

Comment: I have edited to add some information as to when to use which.

Answer (score 4):

I tend to use free functions in unnamed namespace when possible.

So between

```
// header

class A
{
public:
    bool HasCustomProperty() const();
private:
    bool IsOdd() const;
    bool IsHappy() const;
private:
    int a;
};

// cpp

bool A::HasCustomProperty() const
{
    return IsOdd() && IsHappy();
}
```

and

```
// header

class A
{
public:
    bool HasCustomProperty() const();
private:
    static bool IsOdd(int n);
    static bool IsHappy(int n);
private:
    int a;
};

// cpp

bool A::HasCustomProperty() const
{
    return IsOdd(a) && IsHappy(a);
}
```

and

```
// header

class A
{
public:
    bool HasCustomProperty() const();
private:
    int a;
};

// cpp
namespace {
    bool IsOdd(int n);
    bool IsHappy(int n);
}

bool A::HasCustomProperty() const
{
    return IsOdd(a) && IsHappy(a);
}
```

I choose the last one.

Comment: One point to note is that there is only one anonymous namespace in a compilation unit. If multiple headers use anonymous namespaces then they are visible to each other which could result in unexpected results.

Comment: @AndyBrown: I don't use unnamed namespace in header, and it is true that functions inside unnamed namespace are mostly equivalent to static function so file scope (and as header are included possibly in several translation unit, those function should not be inside headers).

Answer (score 1):

They are two different things and are not alternates:

const member functions are not allowed to modify class instant data.
static member functions do not have an associated class instance.

Using OP's example class definintion then in inplementstion ...

```
bool Foo::IsSomething(int* n)
{
   return *n < *a_; // not ok. static method has no this    
}


bool Foo::IsASomething() const
{
   return (*a_ > 8) // ok as member a_ not changed
}

bool Foo::IsASomething() const
{
    *a_ +=4;   // not ok as a_ cannot be changed by const member
    return (*a_ > 8);
}
```

Comment: I understand that const member functions are not allowed to modify data members, and that static member functions are not even allowed to read them. But by passing in data members as parameters to the static function, you can get the same thing done as with a const member function.